# Why does PowerShell 7 revert to black on white after setting PSReadLine color(s)

Tags: powershell

Rather than going in an setting default colors on any machine where I would be using PowerShell, I created a profile with code to do the color setting, so I could just copy the profile from machine to machine. Setting the console colors works fine, however, setting the PSReadline color(s) changes the console white on black. Here is the code:

```
$consoleColorRaw = [int]0
$consoleColorError = [int]1
$consoleColorWarning = [int]2
$consoleColorDebug = [int]3
$consoleColorVerbose = [int]4
$consoleColorProgress = [int]5

function checkIfEnumColor($localColor)
{
  switch($localColor.ToLower())
  {
    "black" {Break}
    "darkBlue" {Break}
    "darkGreen" {Break}
    "darkCyan" {Break}
    "darkRed" {Break}
    "darkMagenta" {Break}
    "darkYellow" {Break}
    "gray" {Break}
    "darkGray" {Break}
    "blue" {Break}
    "green" {Break}
    "cyan" {Break}
    "red" {Break}
    "magenta" {Break}
    "yellow" {Break}
    "white" {Break}
    default { return $false }
  }

  return $true
}


function Color-Console($localWhich, $fg, $bg)
{
  $doClearHost = $false

  $localValue = checkIfEnumColor $bg
 
  if ($localValue -eq $false)
  {
    Write-Host ("Attempting to set background to non-enum value({0})." -f $bg)
    $doClearHost = $false;
  }
  else
  {
    $localValue = checkIfEnumColor $fg

    if ($localValue -eq $false)
    {
      Write-Output ("Attempting to set foreground to non-enum value({0})." -f $fg)
      $doClearHost = $false;
    }
    else
    {
      switch($localWhich)
      {
        $consoleColorRaw { $Host.ui.rawui.foregroundcolor = $fg; $Host.ui.rawui.backgroundcolor = $bg; Break }
        $consoleColorError { $Host.PrivateData.ErrorForegroundColor = $fg; $Host.PrivateData.ErrorBackgroundColor = $bg; Break }
        $consoleColorWarning { $Host.PrivateData.WarningForegroundColor = $fg; $Host.PrivateData.WarningBackgroundColor = $bg; Break }
        $consoleColorDebug { $Host.PrivateData.DebugForegroundColor = $fg; $Host.PrivateData.DebugBackgroundColor = $bg; Break }
        $consoleColorVerbose { $Host.PrivateData.VerboseForegroundColor = $fg; $Host.PrivateData.VerboseBackgroundColor = $bg; Break }
        $consoleColorProgress { $Host.PrivateData.ProgressForegroundColor = $fg; $Host.PrivateData.ProgressBackgroundColor = $bg; Break }

        default { $doClearHost = $false; Break }
      }
    }
  }

  if ($doClearHost -eq $true)
  {
    Clear-Host
  }
}

# I used the documentation in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#3-bit_and_4-bit
# to figure out the numbers for the ansi codes... The dark colors use the 30's and 40's
# and the regular colors use the 90's and 100's (bright colors)
function setPSReadlineColor($localWhich, $foreG, $backG)
{
  $fg = 0;
  $bg = 0;

  switch($foreG.ToLower())
  {
    "black" {$fg = 30;Break}
    "darkRed" {$fg = 31;Break}
    "darkGreen" {$fg = 32;Break}
    "darkYellow" {$fg = 33;Break}
    "darkBlue" {$fg = 34;Break}
    "darkMagenta" {$fg = 35;Break}
    "darkCyan" {$fg = 36;Break}
    "darkGray" {$fg = 37;Break}
    "gray" {$fg = 90;Break}
    "red" {$fg = 91;Break}
    "green" {$fg = 92;Break}
    "yellow" {$fg = 93;Break}
    "blue" {$fg = 94;Break}
    "magenta" {$fg = 95;Break}
    "cyan" {$fg = 96;Break}
    "white" {$fg = 97;Break}
    default {Write-Host ("Attempting to set '{0}' foreground color to non-enum value({1})." -f $localWhich, $foreG); return }
  }

  switch($backG.ToLower())
  {
    "black" {$bg = 40;Break}
    "darkRed" {$bg = 41;Break}
    "darkGreen" {$bg = 42;Break}
    "darkYellow" {$bg = 43;Break}
    "darkBlue" {$bg = 44;Break}
    "darkMagenta" {$bg = 45;Break}
    "darkCyan" {$bg = 46;Break}
    "darkGray" {$bg = 47;Break}
    "gray" {$bg = 100;Break}
    "red" {$bg = 101;Break}
    "green" {$bg = 102;Break}
    "yellow" {$bg = 103;Break}
    "blue" {$bg = 104;Break}
    "magenta" {$bg = 105;Break}
    "cyan" {$bg = 106;Break}
    "white" {$bg = 107;Break}
    default {Write-Host ("Attempting to set '{0}' background color to non-enum value({1})." -f $localWhich, $backG);return }
  }

  $newColor = "$([char]0x1b)[{0};{1}m" -f $fg, $bg
  Set-PSReadLineOption -Colors @{$localWhich = $newColor}
}

Color-Console $consoleColorRaw "DarkMagenta" "Gray"
#Color-Console $consoleColorError "Red" "Gray"
Color-Console $consoleColorError "Yellow" "DarkCyan"
Color-Console $consoleColorWarning "Magenta" "Gray"
Color-Console $consoleColorDebug "Yellow" "Gray"
Color-Console $consoleColorVerbose "Green" "Gray"
Color-Console $consoleColorProgress "Cyan" "Gray"

setPSReadlineColor "Command" "Magenta" "White"
setPSReadlineColor "Variable" "Green" "Gray"
```

Hopefully someone can find whatever I'm doing wrong :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found that powershell 7 (compared to 5.1 at least) saves its profile to a different location, so double-check:

```
# PS5
$profile
C:\users\username\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1

# PS7
$profile
C:\users\username\Documents\PowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
```

I found that  `Set-PSReadLineOption` will set your text color to default if you set an invalid ansi escape sequence. There is different behavior between versions though:

```
# PS5: No error, but sets color to terminal default (white in my case)
Set-PSReadLineOption -Colors @{Command='Magenta,Yellow'}

# PS7: Errors out
Set-PSReadLineOption -Colors @{Command='Magenta,Yellow'}
[Error] Set-PSReadLineOption: 'Magenta,Yellow' is not a valid color value.  It must be a ConsoleColor, ANSI escape sequence, or RGB value with optional leading '#'.
```

I put those two suggestions first, because the script in your question pasted as-is into my profile works for me in both powershell 5.1 and 7.1.

What terminal are you using? The built-in terminal/cmd, PS Core, ISE, VS Code, or the new Windows Terminal? They behave mostly the same in this regard, but may help explain what you're seeing.

Comment: I'm running PowerShell 7.1.3, I downloaded it from "https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/tag/v7.1.3". "C:\Users\redacted\Documents\PowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1" is where the profile resides. The console colors are fine, The PSReadLine colors are "fine". But, if you type a command line that has spaces in it, the spaces will be black, and if you erase the entire line (ESC) the erased area will be black. As I type, I've launched a new shell, and cannot reproduce the entire behavior of white and black, though, after a space, the bg is black, though, fg is unchanged.

Comment: Ah, type in a command, ESC (to erase command), then Ctrl-L to erase screen, reverts console colors to fg White, bg Black. It looks likes it is only cosmetic, as typing in a new command is with the original colors, and running command (that overflows screen, so scrolling occurs) returns to "normal".

Comment: @renfrow oh, that specific behavior is a psreadline bug  (https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/7494). Try updating it following the steps here?: https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine#upgrading
It still does it for me even on the newest prerelease version, but maybe you can find a solution for your situation.

Comment: I want to suggest altering your script to update the default color preferences in the registry, or copying the .lnk file over (which embeds some color preferences) instead of running current-console-session-only color changes. Then it's just a run-once set up my environment instead of something you have to watch load up. Just personal preference though